# nrvo disabling and copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, nrvo

I am a bit confused on how the compiler works
i compiled the prog with g++ -fno-elide-constructors test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class c
{
  int i;
public:
  ~c(){cout<<"Destroying"<<endl;}
  c(){cout<<"Constructing"<<endl;}
  c(const c &a){cout<<"Copy Constructing"<<endl; this->i = a.i;}
  int get_i(){cout<<"Getting "<<i<<endl;return i;}
  void set_i(int i){cout<<"Setting"<<endl; this->i=i;}
  c operator=(c op2) {cout<<"Assignemnt operator"<<endl;  i = op2.i; return *this; }
};

c f(){
    c obj;
    obj.set_i(1);
    return obj;
}
void f1() {
    c obj1 = f();
    c obj2 = obj1;
    obj2.get_i();
}
void f2() {
    c obj1 = f();
    c obj2;
    obj2 = obj1;
    obj2.get_i();
}
int main() {
    cout<<"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"<<endl;
    f1();
    cout<<"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"<<endl;
    f2();
    cout<<"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
output:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Constructing
Setting
Copy Constructing
Destroying
Copy Constructing
Destroying
Copy Constructing
Getting 1
Destroying
Destroying
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Constructing
Setting
Copy Constructing
Destroying
Copy Constructing
Destroying
Constructing
Copy Constructing
Assignemnt operator
Copy Constructing
Destroying
Destroying
Getting 1
Destroying
Destroying
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The output for f1 was ok, but in f2 i am getting copy const after assignment operator as well, why is that happening?

Comment: You assignment operator `c operator=(c op2)` passes the parameter by value - so has to create an extra copy. Also, it is usual to return a reference and not another copy.

Comment: got that corrected, but still i have a copy constructor after assignment operator, I was confused for that.. From where is that copy constructor invoked, i thought obj2 = obj1; (in f2) would just invoke assignment operator only